# LCA - groups under continuous homomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, group-homomorphism, continuous-homomorphisms

can someone help me out with this question? LCA stands for Locally compact Hausdorff abelian group. The question is posted in the attached image

[image]

> Let $A$ and $B$ be LCA-groups and $H$ a (not necessarily closed) finitely generated subgroup of $A$. 
>   If $f$ is a continuous homomorphism of $A$ into $B$ such that the kernel of $f$ lies wholly in $H$ and its topologically isomorphic to $Z^n$, for some $n\ge1$, and such that $f(H)$ contains a subgroup topologically isomorphic to $Z$, show that $H$ contains a subgroup topologically isomorphic to $Z^{n+1}$.

Comment: Maybe you could mention where the problem comes from (in the other words, you could [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

We don’t have much choice to find this subgroup. Let $Z$ be a subgroup of the group $f(H)$, topologically isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. Put $D=\ker f$ and $C=f^{-1}(Z)$. Since the map $f$ is continuous, the group $C$ is a closed subgroup of a locally compact group $G$. So $C$ is a locally compact group too. By Theorem 2.3 from [HC], every locally compact Hausdorff space is Baire. So the space $C$ is Baire. Since $C$ is a countable Baire topological group, it is discrete. It is well-known, that if a quotient group $C/D$ of an abelian group $C$ by its subgroup $D$ is a free group then $D$ is a direct summand of the group $C$ (see, for instance,  [Kur, the end of $\S 19$]). Since the group $C/D$ is (algebraically) isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, and the group $D$ is isomorphic to the group $\Bbb Z^{n}$, the group $C$ is isomorphic to he group $\Bbb Z^{n+1}$. Since the group $C$ is discrete, it is topologically isomorphic to the group $\Bbb Z^{n+1}$.

*Remark 1*. We did not use the fact that the group $H$ is finitely generated.

*Remark 2*. It is a following useful theorem  (see, [Pon, Th. 13]). Let $G$ be a locally compact $\sigma$-compact topological group and $N_1,\dots, N_k$ be closed normal subgroups of the group $G$.  If $G$ algebraically splits into a direct product of its subgroups $N_1,\dots, N_k$ then the topological group $G$ splits into a direct product of its subgroups $N_1,\dots, N_k$ too.

*References*

[HC] R. C. Haworth, R. C. McCoy, *[Baire spaces](http://static.205.58.76.144.clients.your-server.de/book/1415531)*, Warszawa, Panstwowe Wydawnictwo Naukowe, 1977.

[Kur] A. G. Kurosh, *Group theory*, 3nd ed., Nauka, Moskow, 1967. (in Russian)

[Pon] L. S. Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).